# Append list to dataframe (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have a datframe that looks something like this:

```
id  |  item    |  amount
1   |  item_a  |  17
2   |  item_b  |  5
3   |  item_c  |  9
```

I also got a list with exactly the same amount of entrys like my dataframe:

```
list_price = [245, 189, 99]
```

Now I'm failing to append my list to my dataframe to create something like this:

```
id  |  item    |  amount  |  price
1   |  item_a  |  17      |  245
2   |  item_b  |  5       |  189
3   |  item_c  |  9       |  99
```

I've tried the 'lambda'-function, but it didn't work - or I'm doing it wrong!?

Does anyone now the answer?

Comment: `df['price'] = list_price`??

Comment: Thank you! Much easier solution than I thought!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that your dataset is called `df`.

Then, you can use:

```
list_price = [245, 189, 99]
df.insert(3,"Price",list_price)
df.head()

id  |  item    |  amount  |  price
1   |  item_a  |  17      |  245
2   |  item_b  |  5       |  189
3   |  item_c  |  9       |  99
```

Or, alternatively, use `df[price] = list_price`

Answer (score 1):

**Hope** this helps you.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'item':['item_a', 'item_b', 'item_c'], 'amount':[17, 5, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

list_price = [245, 189, 99]
df['price'] = list_price 

print(df)
```

**[Output]:**

> ```
>      item  amount  price
> 0  item_a      17    245
> 1  item_b       5    189
> 2  item_c       9     99
> ```